# javascript why isNaN(new Date()) is false

Tags: javascript, function

Hi I'm looking for a good explanation for this simple code

why `isNaN(new Date(some date))` gives `false`? (typeof return object)

This is an object and as far as i know isNaN function explicitly converts to  a number, so if I pass different object to isNaN it returns true.

Comment: Well, what does `+new Date()` give you? Not not a number (for valid dates)

Comment: That actually depends on `some date`. If it is invalid, your expression would give `true`.

Comment: See also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1353684/1338292) and [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3340055/how-to-check-if-new-datesome-date-was-able-to-parse-correctly).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The first thing that `isNaN()` does is convert its parameter to a number (as you yourself wrote). If the parameter is an object, that's done by calling the `.valueOf()` method of the object. In the case of Date instances that returns the timestamp, and it won't be `NaN` for any valid Date.

Try this:

```
alert(isNaN({ valueOf: function() { return 12; } }));
```

And for an invalid date:

```
alert(isNaN(new Date("potatoes")));
```

That'll be `true`. If you want a stricter `isNaN` you can use `Number.isNaN`:

```
alert(Number.isNaN(NaN)); // true
```

The version of `isNaN` on the Number constructor won't coerce its argument to a number; it's job is to say whether the thing you pass in is the `NaN` value, without any type casting. So by that function, there's one and only one `NaN`.

Comment: This is not true anymore. The line `alert(Number.isNaN(new Date()));` now also returns false (see https://jsfiddle.net/wkrhut9f/)

Comment: @NoRyb that's interesting, thanks — I think I just whipped out a bad example here.

Answer (score 1):

Checking with isNaN tries to convert its parameter to number and if this is not a number then only it gives you the result true. But if the date passed as the parameter it shows you the false as it is converted to number.

Whatever you pass in the parameter if that returns number successfully then it give you the result to be false else it gives you the true.